# jQuery calling element located inside append() with ID

Tags: jquery, append

I'm working on a dynamic web project using Jsf and jquery ..

```
$(function(){

 for(var i = 0 ; i &lt; entitesFilleList.length ; i++){

    var nomEntite = entitesFilleList[i].nom;
    var $nomEntiteMere = entitesFilleList[i].entiteMere.nom;
    $nomEntiteMere = $nomEntiteMere.replace(/\s+/g, '');

    var contentMere = $('#'+$nomEntiteMere).html();                         
    var nomEntiteID = nomEntite.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    var lesCollaborateurs = $('.collaborateurs_of_'+nomEntiteID).text();

    var motherContent = $('#'+$nomEntiteMere).html();                               
    motherContent += '<li id="id_'+nomEntiteID+'"><span class="nomEntite">'+nomEntite+'</span><br/><ul id="'+nomEntiteID+'"></ul><a style="cursor:pointer" class="link" id="link_'+nomEntiteID+'">Equipe</a></li>';
    $('#'+$nomEntiteMere).html(motherContent);

  }

    $('a.link').click(function(){
        alert('I am clicked');
    })
})
```

the thing is when I click the link, the alert does not pop up, but when I add onclick="alert('I am clicked')" inside the  tag, the alert does pop up.

Hope anyone can help 
thanks in advance

Comment: can you add your html for a

Comment: `<a style="cursor:pointer" class="link" id="link_'+nomEntiteID+'">Equipe</a>`

Comment: you want specific link to be clicked or you need every link to execute the same function?

Comment: check my ans for hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work for you...

```
$(function(){

     for(var i = 0 ; i &lt; entitesFilleList.length ; i++){

        var nomEntite = entitesFilleList[i].nom;
        var $nomEntiteMere = entitesFilleList[i].entiteMere.nom;
        $nomEntiteMere = $nomEntiteMere.replace(/\s+/g, '');

        var contentMere = $('#'+$nomEntiteMere).html();                         
        var nomEntiteID = nomEntite.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        var lesCollaborateurs = $('.collaborateurs_of_'+nomEntiteID).text();

        var motherContent = $('#'+$nomEntiteMere).html();                               
        motherContent += '<li id="id_'+nomEntiteID+'"><span class="nomEntite">'+nomEntite+'</span><br/><ul id="'+nomEntiteID+'"></ul><a style="cursor:pointer" class="link" id="link_'+nomEntiteID+' onClick = "TestFunction(link_'+nomEntiteID+')">' + Equipe + '</a></li>';
        $('#'+$nomEntiteMere).append(motherContent);
      }

    })
    function TestFunction(e){
        console.log("Link with id " + e + "is clicked.");
        }
```

Comment: it works perfectly but when i want to do something with the clicked ID, nothing happen ..

Comment: what you want to do with ID?

Comment: why downvote, whoever voted could you explain why downvote when he is saying its working perfectly ok?

Comment: @ZiOS hope its working for your consider accepting if it works.